# Drupal install in sub folder

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to install a drupal site that I built a while back. I put it in a sub folder for viewing purposes and am having trouble logging in. I got the site installed, the DB connected but when I go to myurl.com/sitename/user I get a 404 error. The site is in  maintenance mode so I can't get into the backend system. I know the site is partially working as when I go to myurl.com/sitename I get the maintenance page with all broken links. I did some searching and made sure my .htacces file was updated with this code:

```
RewriteBase /sitename
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

But still not working...
What else should I be doing here?
THanks

Comment: You put your site in a subdomain of the root?

Comment: yes example: myurl.com/sitename/

Comment: You said you put your drupal site in a sub folder for viewing purposes. Sub folder of WHAT? We need to know this because it may be the location of where you are locating your drupal install that can be a problem.

Comment: A subfolder of my testing url. The entire install is in the sitename folder... is that any clearer?

Comment: Make sure that in the settings.php file of your test site the base url is correct.

Comment: Also, you might want to try to log into the system using ?q=user/login to be able to get it out of maintenance mode.

Comment: I tried that but it rewrites the url to user/login and gives a 404. I looked for the base url in setting.php but couldn't find it...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879190/how-to-set-the-base-url-in-drupal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to configure your base url in your settings.php file and revert your .htaccess to the default from drupal.